# solr date stats query

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have a SOLR repository where I store some events. Event date field (eventdate) is stored in the format `yyyymmdd` as `int`. I need to get a stats of events per year in SOLR. In other words if it were a SQL database I would have done `select count(*),substring(eventdate,0,4) group by substring(eventdate,0,4)`.    How can I do that with SOLR?

Answer (score 0):

Try to divide the `eventdate` by 10000 and cast it to int so you could separate the first 4 digits of the number.

Try this:

```
select count(*) group by cast((eventdate/10000) as int)
```

> Second Solution

After seeing your update i understood what you want to achive so what you need to do is to query all the events that occur in a specific year meaning:

```
eventdate > YYYY0000 and eventdate <= yyyy1232
```

because your int is built in this format `yyyymmdd` you can guarantee that all eventdates are in one sequence.

Comment: Sorry Shlomi, the question is for SOLR repository, I have just edited for being more explicit. Thanks